# Remapping a Family of Shortcuts

Tags: key-bindings, nmap

I would like to remap/create the family of shortcuts starting with <kbd>d</kbd> into a version that does not yank it to any register.

Is there a programmatic way of doing this or do I have to do it manually?

For example, my current attempt version of doing this would be:

```
noremap <leader>dd "_dd
noremap <leader>diw "_diw
noremap <leader>daw "_daw
...
```

Remark: Currently, only the `<leader>dd` version is actually working (if anyone knows what I'm doing wrong with the others).

The idea is to find out if there is some sort of regex for families of shortcus.

For example, could we use something like `"_d*` to catch anything after the <kbd>d</kbd>?

Comment: "Mapping", not "remapping". "Commands", nor "shortcuts".

Comment: Does `nnoremap <leader>d "_d` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do:

```
for tobj in ['d', 'aw', 'ai']
  execute 'nnoremap <leader>d' .. tobj .. ' "_d' .. tobj
endfor
```

Or:

```
nnoremap <leader>d "_d
```